# How can I stop jetty server without restarting repl

Tags: clojure, jetty, boot-clj

Let's say I have a trivial boot-clj task that uses `'[pandeiro.boot-http :refer [serve]]`. If I make changes and need to restart the task it would complain that the port is already in use. Is there a way to kill jetty server without having to restart repl?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only this many people use this pattern:

```
(defonce running-server (atom nil))
(defn stop-server [] (@running-server))
(defn go []
  (reset! running-server
            (org.httpkit.server/run-server 
             ... your stuff here ...))
```

If this is a longer term project starting with something like the component framework solves this problem in a much more elegant way and allows for many dependent components (hence the name). This is a [good place to get started](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded) and worth reading before starting your next project.

Answer (score 0):

`pandeiro.boot-http` supports reloading of your handler so you don't have to restart the `serve` task. You need to configure it with [`:reload` set to `true`](https://github.com/pandeiro/boot-http#-r----reload):

On command line:

```
boot serve -H myapp.server/app -R wait
```

Or in your boot script:

```
(boot (serve :handler 'myapp.server/app :reload true) (wait))
```

For regular static files `serve` always returns the current version from the disk so there is no need for reloading for them.

If you really need to restart the task I guess you might be affected by [issue](https://github.com/pandeiro/boot-http/issues/25) in `pandeiro.boot-http` and might need to contact its maintainer.